# Arduino How can I add 30s delay and turn off the led to the following code

Tags: arduino-uno

```
const int buttonPin =  2;
boolean currentState = LOW;
boolean lastState    = LOW;
boolean stateChange  = false;

int currentButton = 0;
int lastButton    = 4;
int ledArray[]    = {9, 10, 11, 12};
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000 ;

void setup() {
        pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            pinMode(ledArray[i],OUTPUT);
        }
        Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop(){
            currentState = debounceButton();
            stateChange = checkForChange(currentState, lastState);
            currentButton = getButtonNumber(lastButton, currentState, stateChange);
            indicatorLight(currentButton);
            lastState  = currentState;
            lastButton = currentButton;
}


boolean debounceButton()
            {
            boolean firstCheck   = LOW;
            boolean secondCheck  = LOW;
            boolean current = LOW;  
            firstCheck  = digitalRead(buttonPin);
            delay(50);
            secondCheck = digitalRead(buttonPin);  
                    if (firstCheck == secondCheck){
                        current = firstCheck;
                    }
            return current;
}


boolean checkForChange(boolean current, boolean last)
        {
        boolean change;  
                if (current != last){
                    change = true;
                }
                        else {
                        change = false;
                        }  
                return change;
}

int getButtonNumber(int button, boolean state, boolean change)
            { 
            if (change == true && state == LOW){
                button++;
                        if (button > 3){
                        button = 0;
                        }
                        Serial.println("g");
            
            }
            return button;
}



void indicatorLight(int button)
         {
                for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                            digitalWrite(ledArray[i], LOW);
                        }
                        digitalWrite(ledArray[button], HIGH);
  }
```

Comment: Use `millis()` to capture a timestamp of when you are turning the LED on, then use that in `loop()` to check, if more than 30s passed. In that if statement turn off all LEDs. Refer to the BlinkWithoutDelay example, that comes with the Arduino IDE

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea to debounce the buttons, but there is a 50 ms delay per button which blocks the loop for a total of 200 ms with four buttons.

So consider using a non-blocking debouncer of which there are many examples on the internet, but here is a [simple debouncer](https://github.com/TimMathias/Arduino-Debouncer/) I put on GitHub. It could be implemented something like the following example:

```cpp
#include "debouncer.h"

const uint16_t LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms = 2000;  // milliseconds. For testing.
//const uint16_t LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms = 30000;  // milliseconds.

struct ButtonLed
{
  Debouncer button;
  byte button_pin;
  byte led_pin;
};

const ButtonLed BUTTONS_LEDS[] = 
{
  { Debouncer(5, 50, LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms), 5, 11 },
  { Debouncer(4, 50, LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms), 4, 10 },
  { Debouncer(3, 50, LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms), 3, 9 },
  { Debouncer(2, 50, LED_OFF_TIME_DELAY_ms), 2, 8 }
};

void setup()
{
  for (const auto& button_led : BUTTONS_LEDS)
  {
    pinMode(button_led.button_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(button_led.led_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(button_led.led_pin, LOW);
  }
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  uint16_t timestamp = millis();

  //
  // TASK 1: Read the buttons and set their corresponding LEDs.
  //

  for (const auto& button_led : BUTTONS_LEDS)
  {
    button_led.button.Update();
    if (button_led.button.Fall())
    {
      digitalWrite(button_led.led_pin, HIGH);
    }
    else if (button_led.button.RepeatCount() == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite(button_led.led_pin, LOW);
    }
  }

  //
  // TASK 2: Blink the inbuilt LED.
  //

  const uint16_t LED_BLINK_INTERVAL = 100;
  static uint16_t led_blink_previous_timestamp = timestamp;
  static bool led_state = false;
  if (timestamp - led_blink_previous_timestamp >= LED_BLINK_INTERVAL)
  {
    led_state = !led_state;
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, led_state);
    led_blink_previous_timestamp += LED_BLINK_INTERVAL;
  }
}
```

And here it is in action in the Wokwi simulator:

[image]